# Integration Virtualscroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

first i' m sorry in advance i'm new in javascript :p
i' m trying to integrate the virtualscroll.js i found [here](http://bartekdrozdz.com/docs/#virtualscroll)
in my webpage no problem for the moment but ...
I can' t find a solution for integrate this script to all my page and 
have my home section that taking 100% of the browser :/
also i can' t find how to keep my menu having a scroll spy ( when i m scrolling on the page the underline of the menu move automatically ) 
i saw examples of the effect i want like:
http://www.studiofatale.com
the home page is always in 100% of the browser :/ 
i understand that i can' t get all my section at 100% of the browser but 
i only need my home page like that

SO there is my website code:

```js
// JavaScript Document

/*
 * jQuery One Page Nav Plugin
 * http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Trevor Davis (http://trevordavis.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * Uses the same license as jQuery, see:
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * @version 3.0.0
 *
 * Example usage:
 * $('#nav').onePageNav({
 *   currentClass: 'current',
 *   changeHash: false,
 *   scrollSpeed: 750
 * });
 */

;(function($, window, document, undefined){

 // our plugin constructor
 var OnePageNav = function(elem, options){
  this.elem = elem;
  this.$elem = $(elem);
  this.options = options;
  this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
  this.$win = $(window);
  this.sections = {};
  this.didScroll = false;
  this.$doc = $(document);
  this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
 };

 // the plugin prototype
 OnePageNav.prototype = {
  defaults: {
   navItems: 'a',
   currentClass: 'current',
   changeHash: false,
   easing: 'swing',
   filter: '',
   scrollSpeed: 750,
   scrollThreshold: 0.5,
   begin: false,
   end: false,
   scrollChange: false
  },

  init: function() {
   // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
   // globally or using an object literal.
   this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

   this.$nav = this.$elem.find(this.config.navItems);

   //Filter any links out of the nav
   if(this.config.filter !== '') {
    this.$nav = this.$nav.filter(this.config.filter);
   }

   //Handle clicks on the nav
   this.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.handleClick, this));

   //Get the section positions
   this.getPositions();

   //Handle scroll changes
   this.bindInterval();

   //Update the positions on resize too
   this.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(this.getPositions, this));

   return this;
  },

  adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
   self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
   $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
  },

  bindInterval: function() {
   var self = this;
   var docHeight;

   self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function() {
    self.didScroll = true;
   });

   self.t = setInterval(function() {
    docHeight = self.$doc.height();

    //If it was scrolled
    if(self.didScroll) {
     self.didScroll = false;
     self.scrollChange();
    }

    //If the document height changes
    if(docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
     self.docHeight = docHeight;
     self.getPositions();
    }
   }, 250);
  },

  getHash: function($link) {
   return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
  },

  getPositions: function() {
   var self = this;
   var linkHref;
   var topPos;
   var $target;

   self.$nav.each(function() {
    linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
    $target = $('#' + linkHref);

    if($target.length) {
     topPos = $target.offset().top;
     self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos);
    }
   });
  },

  getSection: function(windowPos) {
   var returnValue = null;
   var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

   for(var section in this.sections) {
    if((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
     returnValue = section;
    }
   }

   return returnValue;
  },

  handleClick: function(e) {
   var self = this;
   var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
   var $parent = $link.parent();
   var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

   if(!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
    //Start callback
    if(self.config.begin) {
     self.config.begin();
    }

    //Change the highlighted nav item
    self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

    //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
    self.unbindInterval();

    //Scroll to the correct position
    self.scrollTo(newLoc, function() {
     //Do we need to change the hash?
     if(self.config.changeHash) {
      window.location.hash = newLoc;
     }

     //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
     self.bindInterval();

     //End callback
     if(self.config.end) {
      self.config.end();
     }
    });
   }

   e.preventDefault();
  },

  scrollChange: function() {
   var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
   var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
   var $parent;

   //If the position is set
   if(position !== null) {
    $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

    //If it's not already the current section
    if(!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
     //Change the highlighted nav item
     this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

     //If there is a scrollChange callback
     if(this.config.scrollChange) {
      this.config.scrollChange($parent);
     }
    }
   }
  },

  scrollTo: function(target, callback) {
   var offset = $(target).offset().top;

   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
   }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
  },

  unbindInterval: function() {
   clearInterval(this.t);
   this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
  }
 };

 OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

 $.fn.onePageNav = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
   new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
  });
 };

})( jQuery, window , document );
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}


#content {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;

}

    
/*------menu------ */

.menu {
margin-top: 25%;
 position:fixed;
  width: 50%;
  right: -25%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.one.current ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.two.current ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three.current ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four.current ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.one:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}


/*------menu fin------ */

/*------section------ */
.section { 
width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center; display:table; color:#fff; font-size:60px; font-weight:800; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5); letter-spacing:-2px; text-transform:uppercase;
}

.page {
 display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;
}
#home {
 background:rgba(0,153,153,1) center no-repeat fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
}

#work {
 background: rgba(0,102,153,1) center no-repeat fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
}

#about {
 background: rgba(204,102,0,1) center no-repeat fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
}

#contact {
 background: rgba(153,0,102,1) center no-repeat fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
}
/*------section fin------ */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu li:eq(0)').addClass('current');
   $('.menu').onePageNav();
  });
  
 </script>
<body>

  <div class="pace"></div>
  <div id="content">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="one"><a href="#home">home</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#work">work</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#about">about</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>


<div class="section" id="home">
<div class="page">
WELCOME
</div>
</div>

<div class="section"  id="work">
<div class="page">
WORK
</div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="about">
<div class="page">
ABOUT ME
</div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="contact">
<div class="page">
CONTACT
</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what the question at hand is? Running the code snippet seems to have everything working just fine.

Comment: Nevermind I understand the problem now. I have a working solution and will post the answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: hmmm, I think the deeper problem is that you feel the need to use virtual scroll. What are you trying to do with it? Virtual scroll never feels right. There are just too many variations across browsers and OSs and scrolling devices to make it feel anything but a little broken, everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that i have accurately figured out what you wanted to do with this then I have a working solution for you right here:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7ze91vd/3/

the plugin doesn't seem to work on jsfiddle... but the scrolling of the divs should remain the same.

The solution was to set the home div to be a fixed div so it doesn't move when scrolling then just scroll the other divs "on top" of it using a padding div to fill the missing gap from the home div no longer being part of the scroll zone.

I modified the html sections to look like this:

```
<div class="section" id="home">
    <div class="page">
        WELCOME
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="section"  id="padding">
      <div class="page">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section"  id="work">
      <div class="page">
          WORK
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="about">
      <div class="page">
          ABOUT ME
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="contact">
      <div class="page">
          CONTACT
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also had to modify the menu button for the home div from:

```
<li class="one"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li class="one"><a href="#padding">home</a></li>
```

and I modified the css by adding these blocks:

```
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#home {
     position:fixed;
}
ul.menu {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. If its a working solution please accept the answer so the question is resolved.

Comment: So now for include the virtual scroll js inside i just need to make a section that take work to contact ? http://bartekdrozdz.com/test/wheel-simple.html this script need the body in overflow hidden , and the section call by the js in position absolute with a specific width can't be at 100%

Comment: no actually i can' include the virtual scroll :s because that need the body be overflow hidden so if my home page is at 100% i can't scroll

Comment: So i guess I don't fully know the integration you're looking for with virtual scroll. I had assumed you just wanted the scrolling functionality thats currently there in the js fiddle. Could you give me an example of whats missing still and maybe i can find you a solution?

Comment: actually the effect i want include into my page is this one http://bartekdrozdz.com/test/wheel-simple.html   but i want to keep my home page at 100% of the browser at any time the problem is that this script is using a body in overflow hidden so if my home page is at 100% height i can' t scroll in hidden :p this is the best example i find about what i want http://www.studiofatale.com

Comment: Okay, I'm still at work so I'll have to look into this later tonight... So basically the effect from the jsfiddle i posted isn't quite it because you want to get it to also fade away? The way the fiddle was I thought emulated what you needed which was the divs sliding on top of the home page.

Comment: yes the effect you post is one i want but the most important effect i try to include is the virtual scroll effect on the link i post before ( when the user scroll in the page there is an effect of fluidity same there  http://www.bartekdrozdz.com/test/wheel-simple.html

Comment: okay i see, so the most important part you want is to make it fluid scrolling instead of the choppy scrolling that is currently there.

Comment: exactlly in using the script i put below :)

Comment: I spent a bit of time with it today but was not able to get a working smooth scrolling effect. I had coded out my own a couple of different ways but it always had one drawback or another. Unfortunately my testing environment is making it hard to use some of these javascript libraries and even my jquery is acting up...Are you sure that you need to use this virtual scroll js? In researching the problem I found many other "smooth scroll" javascript files. Might one of those offer you a solution instead?

Comment: i m still trying to intégrate it.. if someone can contact me for i send him my code because it s not working in the jsfiddl e

Comment: If you send me your current code I can take another look at it tonight... I'm not sure how much more can be done.. in general scroll effects are finicky and not easy to get a nice effect across multiple platforms for.

Comment: ok send me a message on my mail i will send you the page: thibaud.allie@hotmail.fr

Answer (score 0):

there is the virtual scroll js

```js
var VirtualScroll = (function(document) {

 var vs = {};

 var numListeners, listeners = [], initialized = false;

 var touchStartX, touchStartY;

 // [ These settings can be customized with the options() function below ]
 // Mutiply the touch action by two making the scroll a bit faster than finger movement
 var touchMult = 2;
 // Firefox on Windows needs a boost, since scrolling is very slow
 var firefoxMult = 15;
 // How many pixels to move with each key press
 var keyStep = 120;
 // General multiplier for all mousehweel including FF
 var mouseMult = 1;

 var bodyTouchAction;

 var hasWheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document;
 var hasMouseWheelEvent = 'onmousewheel' in document;
 var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document;
 var hasTouchWin = navigator.msMaxTouchPoints && navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 1;
 var hasPointer = !!window.navigator.msPointerEnabled;
 var hasKeyDown = 'onkeydown' in document;

 var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1;

 var event = {
  y: 0,
  x: 0,
  deltaX: 0,
  deltaY: 0,
  originalEvent: null
 };

 vs.on = function(f) {
  if(!initialized) initListeners(); 
  listeners.push(f);
  numListeners = listeners.length;
 }

 vs.options = function(opt) {
  keyStep = opt.keyStep || 120;
  firefoxMult = opt.firefoxMult || 15;
  touchMult = opt.touchMult || 2;
  mouseMult = opt.mouseMult || 1;
 }

 vs.off = function(f) {
  listeners.splice(f, 1);
  numListeners = listeners.length;
  if(numListeners <= 0) destroyListeners();
 }

 var notify = function(e) {
  event.x += event.deltaX;
  event.y += event.deltaY;
  event.originalEvent = e;

  for(var i = 0; i < numListeners; i++) {
   listeners[i](event);
  }
 }

 var onWheel = function(e) {
  // In Chrome and in Firefox (at least the new one)
  event.deltaX = e.wheelDeltaX || e.deltaX * -1;
  event.deltaY = e.wheelDeltaY || e.deltaY * -1;

  // for our purpose deltamode = 1 means user is on a wheel mouse, not touch pad 
  // real meaning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent#Delta_modes
  if(isFirefox && e.deltaMode == 1) {
   event.deltaX *= firefoxMult;
   event.deltaY *= firefoxMult;
  } 

  event.deltaX *= mouseMult;
  event.deltaY *= mouseMult;

  notify(e);
 }

 var onMouseWheel = function(e) {
  // In Safari, IE and in Chrome if 'wheel' isn't defined
  event.deltaX = (e.wheelDeltaX) ? e.wheelDeltaX : 0;
  event.deltaY = (e.wheelDeltaY) ? e.wheelDeltaY : e.wheelDelta;

  notify(e); 
 }

 var onTouchStart = function(e) {
  var t = (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0] : e;
  touchStartX = t.pageX; 
  touchStartY = t.pageY;
 }

 var onTouchMove = function(e) {
  // e.preventDefault(); // < This needs to be managed externally
  var t = (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0] : e;

  event.deltaX = (t.pageX - touchStartX) * touchMult;
  event.deltaY = (t.pageY - touchStartY) * touchMult;
  
  touchStartX = t.pageX;
  touchStartY = t.pageY;

  notify(e);
 }

 var onKeyDown = function(e) {
  // 37 left arrow, 38 up arrow, 39 right arrow, 40 down arrow
  event.deltaX = event.deltaY = 0;
  switch(e.keyCode) {
   case 37:
    event.deltaX = -keyStep;
    break;
   case 39:
    event.deltaX = keyStep;
    break;
   case 38:
    event.deltaY = keyStep;
    break;
   case 40:
    event.deltaY = -keyStep;
    break;
  }

  notify(e);
 }

 var initListeners = function() {
  if(hasWheelEvent) document.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  if(hasMouseWheelEvent) document.addEventListener("mousewheel", onMouseWheel);

  if(hasTouch) {
   document.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart);
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
  }
  
  if(hasPointer && hasTouchWin) {
   bodyTouchAction = document.body.style.msTouchAction;
   document.body.style.msTouchAction = "none";
   document.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onTouchStart, true);
   document.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", onTouchMove, true);
  }

  if(hasKeyDown) document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

  initialized = true;
 }

 var destroyListeners = function() {
  if(hasWheelEvent) document.removeEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  if(hasMouseWheelEvent) document.removeEventListener("mousewheel", onMouseWheel);

  if(hasTouch) {
   document.removeEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart);
   document.removeEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
  }
  
  if(hasPointer && hasTouchWin) {
   document.body.style.msTouchAction = bodyTouchAction;
   document.removeEventListener("MSPointerDown", onTouchStart, true);
   document.removeEventListener("MSPointerMove", onTouchMove, true);
  }

  if(hasKeyDown) document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

  initialized = false;
 }

 return vs;
})(document);
```

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Univers LT 45 Light";
            /* use this to avoid elastic overscroll on desktop (see below for mobile */
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        section {
            /* the scrollable section needs to be positioned absolute, 
               otherwise the margins are not taken into account when measuing height (CSS...) */
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
 
        }

        section div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1000px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #box1 {
   background: rgba(0,153,204,1);
           
       
         
        }

        #box2 {
           
        }

        #box3 {
          
        }

        #box4 {
           
        }

        #box5 {
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: rgb(200, 0, 200);
   bottom: 0;
       
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Virtual scroll demo - simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable = no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/framework/VirtualScroll.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 


    <section>
        <div id="box1" class="point">
        salut a toutes et à tous
        
        </div>
        <div id="box2" class="point">
        
Nulla facilisi. Cras fermentum leo ligula, vitae tristique mi rutrum ac. Vivamus vitae ante eros. Praesent auctor eu leo non dictum. Praesent venenatis ut quam ut cursus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus iaculis, ex eu scelerisque aliquet, ligula nulla semper metus, sit amet molestie leo libero a nisi. Ut egestas orci vel lorem placerat sollicitudin nec congue justo.
        
        </div>
        <div id="box3" class="point">
       
Nulla facilisi. Cras fermentum leo ligula, vitae tristique mi rutrum ac. Vivamus vitae ante eros. Praesent auctor eu leo non dictum. Praesent venenatis ut quam ut cursus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus iaculis, ex eu scelerisque aliquet, ligula nulla semper metus, sit amet molestie leo libero a nisi. Ut egestas orci vel lorem placerat sollicitudin nec congue justo.
        
        </div>
        <div id="box4" class="point">
       

In feugiat nunc at rhoncus vestibulum. Donec blandit id risus eget consectetur. Vestibulum ac felis iaculis, maximus turpis vel, hendrerit eros. Sed sagittis erat eu ante vestibulum efficitur. Proin viverra, ligula at luctus molestie, eros urna lobortis lectus, ut fringilla odio velit a sapien. Sed ultricies ultrices tellus a facilisis. Nam viverra arcu vel purus tempus tristique. Phasellus quis pellentesque arcu, at tincidunt dui. Curabitur imperdiet lorem vel rhoncus imperdiet. Curabitur lacinia purus non lectus posuere consectetur. Ut interdum varius arcu, ac aliquet mi auctor volutpat. Curabitur quam ante, vehicula a nulla quis, porta efficitur neque. Integer ut ornare nulla. Nulla consequat, dui eget luctus placerat, turpis metus ultricies magna, a pulvinar justo mauris sit amet dui. Aliquam vestibulum malesuada sem, sit amet ultrices diam hendrerit a.

Nulla facilisi. Cras fermentum leo ligula, vitae tristique mi rutrum ac. Vivamus vitae ante eros. Praesent auctor eu leo non dictum. Praesent venenatis ut quam ut cursus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus iaculis, ex eu scelerisque aliquet, ligula nulla semper metus, sit amet molestie leo libero a nisi. Ut egestas orci vel lorem placerat sollicitudin nec congue justo.</div>
        <div id="box5">

In feugiat nunc at rhoncus vestibulum. Donec blandit id risus eget consectetur. Vestibulum ac felis iaculis, maximus turpis vel, hendrerit eros. Sed sagittis erat eu ante vestibulum efficitur. Proin viverra, ligula at luctus molestie, eros urna lobortis lectus, ut fringilla odio velit a sapien. Sed ultricies ultrices tellus a facilisis. Nam viverra arcu vel purus tempus tristique. Phasellus quis pellentesque arcu, at tincidunt dui. Curabitur imperdiet lorem vel rhoncus imperdiet. Curabitur lacinia purus non lectus posuere consectetur. Ut interdum varius arcu, ac aliquet mi auctor volutpat. Curabitur quam ante, vehicula a nulla quis, porta efficitur neque. Integer ut ornare nulla. Nulla consequat, dui eget luctus placerat, turpis metus ultricies magna, a pulvinar justo mauris sit amet dui. Aliquam vestibulum malesuada sem, sit amet ultrices diam hendrerit a.

Nulla facilisi. Cras fermentum leo ligula, vitae tristique mi rutrum ac. Vivamus vitae ante eros. Praesent auctor eu leo non dictum. Praesent venenatis ut quam ut cursus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus iaculis, ex eu scelerisque aliquet, ligula nulla semper metus, sit amet molestie leo libero a nisi. Ut egestas orci vel lorem placerat sollicitudin nec congue justo.</div>
    </section>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Grab both red boxes
        var section = document.querySelector("section");

        // Check how much we can scroll. This value is the 
        // height of the scrollable element minus the height of the widow
        var sectionHeight = section.getBoundingClientRect().height - window.innerHeight;

        // Add easing to the scroll. Play with this value to find a setting that you like.
        var ease = 0.1;

        // Store current scroll position
        var targetX = 0, targetY = 0;
        var currentX = 0, currentY = 0;

        // Use this if you want to lock the elastic overscroll on mobile
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

        // Add virtual scroll listener
        VirtualScroll.on(function(e) {

            // Accumulate delta value on each scroll event
            targetY += e.deltaY;
            targetX += e.deltaX;

            // Clamp the value so it doesn't go too far up or down
            // The value needs to be between 0 and -sectionHeight
            targetY = Math.max(-sectionHeight, targetY);
            targetY = Math.min(0, targetY);

        });

        var scroll = function() {
            // Make sure this works across different browsers (use the shim or something)
            requestAnimationFrame(scroll);

            // Get closer to the target value at each frame, using ease. 
            // Other easing methods are also ok.
            currentY += (targetY - currentY) * ease;

            // Uncomment this line to scroll horizontally
            // currentX += (targetX - currentX) * ease;

            // Create the CSS transform string
            // (alternativly: use WebKitCSSMatrix, though it doesn't see any faster (http://jsperf.com/webkitcssmatrix-vs-translate3d)
            var v1 = "translateX(" + currentX + "px) translateY(" + currentY + "px)";// translateZ(0)";
            var v2 = "translateX(" + currentX + "px) translateY(" + currentY + "px)";// translateZ(0)";

            // Apply CSS style
            section.style['webkitTransform'] = v1;
            section.style['msTransform'] = v1;
            section.style.transform = v1;
        }

        // Start the rendering loop function
        scroll();

    </script>

</body>
```

its not working in the edit but the link in the comment is the effect